# How rebuild a jar file?

Tags: java, jar, rebuild

I have a `jar file` with following directory:

```
css/
images/
js/
META-INF/
atlassian-plugin.xml
jira_rtl.properties
LICENSE
```

I want to change the `file.css` in `css` directory and then rebuild `the jar` file.

**How Can I do this in Windows 8.1 OS**?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185408/modifying-a-jar-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WinRAR (or similar) to unzip the `.jar` file and replace the files you need and then re-zip it (using a `.jar` file extension). You may need to rename `[filename].jar` to `[filename].zip` and vice-versa.

Some archivers like [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) even enable you to directly edit from the program and after you save your edits it will automatically update your archive (in this case a zip with a .jar extension). So this is even easier than unpacking all files and packing them again.

There are rare cases where the order of files in the jar matters (OSGi bundles for example), so you have to be careful. But I would say in 99,9% the order does not matter at all.

[**J**ava **AR**chive (`.jar`) format is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) (just) a zipped file with same format as `.zip`, that is why this can be done. The same `.zip` format is used in other archive formats (for example `.swc` for ActionScript/Flash)

Answer (score 4):

Use the following command to update the file via Java's jar utility,

```
<JAVA_HOME>/bin/jar -uvf <jar-file-name> <modified file path>
```

In your case lets say the jar file name is simple.jar,

```
<JAVA_HOME>/bin/jar -uvf simple.jar css/*
```