# Fastest way to create a jar file containing .class files from a jar containing java sources files?

Tags: java

I have some .jar files containing source code. Each one is named `"File1-1.0.4-sources.jar"`. And then there is a corresponding `"File1-1.0.4.jar"` which only contains java class files.

Is there any smart way other than using eclipse to import project, make a change to a specific file and then export the whole project as the .jar file?

As I just have to make little modifications to only one of the file in the whole jar, I was looking for some efficient way.

Comment: You can create a "hot-patch" file pretty quickly (assuming you aren't modifying a `static` global), what kind of "little modifications" and what kind of traceability is required? Can you give us a more complete example? What kind of output do you expect? `File1-1.0.4-patch1.jar`? And if so, what have you already tried or researched here?

Comment: Extract both the jar file using command `jar -xvf fileName.jar` .Then take the java  file you want to modify from extracted source jar compile it  and then replace the  generated  class file with the same class file in directory where you extracted the `File1-1.0.4.jar`. and inside that directory use command `jar cf File1-1.0.4.jar * `. Possible duplicate of  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185408/modifying-a-jar-file)